# Limiting floats to two decimal points in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have values structured like this:

```
14.996
2248.43
-2334.06
12.2333334455 
74.38133333333328
```

And I want it to become this:

```
15.00
2248.43
-2334.06
12.24
74.40
```

Using an sql query in oracle db?
maintaining only 2 decimal points. Tried CAST and TO_NUMBER with formatting but it didn't work.

Comment: `maintaining only 3 decimal points` ... but your expected output has _two_ decimal places, not three.

Comment: Yes there seems to be a confusion. How do you think to round up .233 to .24 while .381 to .4 ?

Comment: i changed maintaining only 3 decimal points to 2 decimal

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan this is the requirement if you could resolve this it will help for all  "How do you think to round up .233 to .24 while .381 to .4 ? "

Answer (score 2):

Well `CAST` can certainly be made to work here, e.g.

```sql
SELECT CAST(74.38133333333328 AS NUMERIC(10,3)) AS output
FROM dual;

-- 74.381
```

For notes, `NUMERIC(10, 3)` means 10 total digits of precision, with 3 of those digits being to the *right* of the decimal point.

Comment: need logic to round up  for all float inside file

Comment: I have a file where one column has FLOOR Data Value. We need to round up to 2 decimal large numbers of data from that column. for that i need logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CEIL` to round up:

```sql
SELECT CEIL(value * 100)/100 FROM table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT    14.996            FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  2248.43             FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT -2334.06             FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT    12.2333334455     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT    74.38133333333328 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | CEILING_VALUE |
> | --- |
> | 15 |
> | 2248.43 |
> | -2334.06 |
> | 12.24 |
> | 74.39 |

If you want to **display** 2 decimal places then use `TO_CHAR`:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(CEIL(value * 100)/100, 'fm999990.00') AS ceiling_value FROM table_name;
```

Which outputs:

> | CEILING_VALUE |
> | --- |
> | 15.00 |
> | 2248.43 |
> | -2334.06 |
> | 12.24 |
> | 74.39 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0764941e2de556ff786bb88b18f4d296)*

Answer (score 0):

This will return 3 decimal places even you only have 2 decimals.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(CAST(-2334.06 AS NUMERIC(10,3)), '9999999999990.999') AS output FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the real question here is how to round numbers using SQL.

Like MT0 already suggested (unfortunately I'm too new here to comment his answer) to round to the next nearest decimal use CEIL.

Examples:

1. To round to the second decimal in 0.01 steps.

```
SELECT 
    CEIL(74.381333333333328 / 0.01) * 0.01 
FROM dual; -- Returns 74.39
```

2. To round to the second decimal in 0.05 steps.

```
SELECT 
    CEIL(74.381333333333328 / 0.05) * 0.05 
FROM dual; -- Returns 74.4
```

For completeness: use FLOOR or ROUND with 0 precision instead of CEIL to round to the previous nearest decimal or mathematically.

Comment: but all the values I mentioned in a file, should execute at once .for that i need logic .

Comment: You should provide more context since in the original question you said "using an sql query in oracle db". You want to process a file using SQL?

Comment: I have a file where one column has FLOOR Data Value. We need to round up to 2 decimal large numbers of data from that column. for that i need logic.

Comment: You have lost me. Maybe you should first create an external table to allow Oracle reading the file as it would be a regular table and then query the external table using SQL. I'm not an expert on that and honestly I do no more see the link to your original question and SQL is not designed to modify files as far as I know.